# Getting checked rows from kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a kendo grid with a checked box column .I have been trying to get the dataitem rows when the corresponding check boxes are checked.On click of a button , I need to get only the checked rows in JSon .Here is a JSfiddle I have been playing with.It gets only the Id rather than the row data.I have been trying to modify so that it can return the entire row data .

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg56P/31/

```
        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductID",
                        fields: {
                            ProductID: {
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true
                            },
                            ProductName: {
                                validation: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            UnitPrice: {
                                type: "number",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    min: 1
                                }
                            },
                            Discontinued: {
                                type: "boolean"
                            },
                            UnitsInStock: {
                                type: "number",
                                validation: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    required: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        //Grid definition
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            //define dataBound event handler

            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                //define template column with checkbox and attach click event handler
                { template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />" },
                "ProductName", {
                    field: "UnitPrice",
                    title: "Unit Price",
                    format: "{0:c}",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    field: "UnitsInStock",
                    title: "Units In Stock",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    field: "Discontinued",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                    title: "&nbsp;",
                    width: "172px"
                }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        //bind click event to the checkbox
        grid.table.on("change", ".checkbox" , selectRow);

        $("#showSelection").bind("click", function () {
            var items = [];
            for(var i in checkedrows){
                if(checkedrows[i]){
                    items.push([i]);
                }
            }

            alert(JSON.stringify(itemss));
        });
    });

    var checkedrows = {};
    var itemss =[];
    //on click of the checkbox:
    function selectRow() {
        var checked = this.checked,
            row = $(this).closest("tr"),
            grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
            dItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        checkedrows[dItem.id] = checked;
        if (checked) {
            itemss.push(dItem)
            //-select the row


        } 
        else
        {
            itemss.pop(dataItem);
        }
    }
```

the row get can be accessed by the dataItem ,but how to get the dataItem based on the index .Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

To get just the checked boxes, I use this

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.tbody.find("input:checked").closest("tr").each(function (index) {
            whatever you need done.
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was correct in 2014 but now the api has improved. You can use the following snippet to get the data items. Note that checked rows will also be selected and thus be returned from the grid.select() call.

```
//get the grid
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

// array to store the dataItems
var selected = [];

//get all selected rows (those which have the checkbox checked)  
grid.select().each(function(){

    //push the dataItem into the array
    selected.push(grid.dataItem(this));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the selected items by `uid`, then get them from the data source when needed.

Select handler:

```
function selectRow() {
    var checked = this.checked,
        row = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    checkedrows[dataItem.uid] = checked;
}
```

To get the serialized array of items:

```
function getSerializedSelectedRows() {
    var items = [],
        item,
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    for (var uid in checkedrows) {
        if (checkedrows.hasOwnProperty(uid)) {
            if (checkedrows[uid]) {
                item = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
                items.push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(items);
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/Xg56P/41/))

Answer (score 0):

You can check this

```
var gridData2 = $("#CustomerAccountManagerKendoGrid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();  

var gEmpID2 = GetSelectedEmpID(gridData2); 


function GetSelectedEmpID(gridData) {  
     for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {  
       if (gridData[i].SelectStatus == true) {  
         return gridData[i].GEmployeeGenInfoID;  
       }  
     }  
   }
```

you can also see [this](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/kendo-grid-checkbox-check-validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with older versions of Kendo Grid which does not have the .select() method, then, one way would be like below:

```
var allSelected = $("#gridName tr.k-state-selected");
    $.each(allSelected, function (e) {
        var row = $(this);
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        //Do whatever you need with the dataItem
    });
```